# Empty element not allowed

Tags: powershell

I can't seem to export anything into CSV. I did some browsing and reading, but having hard time converting my script.

```
$allmailbox = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize 20
foreach ($Mailbox in $allmailbox) {
    Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity ($mailbox.alias+':\calendar') |
        Where {
            $_.User -like "Anonymous" -and
            $_.AccessRights -ne "None" -or
            $_.User -like "Default" -and
            $_.AccessRights -ne "None" -or
            $_.User -like "Default" -and
            $_.AccessRights -ne "AvailabilityOnly"
        } |
        select Identity, User, AccessRights
} | Export-Csv C:\CSVs\calstest.csv
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to combine your queries into parentheses, posted a suggested answer

Comment: Check operator precedence. It may require using parentheses to explicitly specify the comparisons. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operator_precedence?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 1):

The empty element not allowed is referring to the `|` at the end of your `foreach`. The way that your loop is structured does not allow the pipe. Below shows a different approach that can work.

Below should get you everything in one CSV file:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize 20 | foreach {Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $($_.Alias+":\calendar") |  Where {$_.User -like "Anonymous" -and $_.AccessRights -ne "None" -or $_.User -like "Default" -and $_.AccessRights -ne "None" -or $_.User -like "Default" -and $_.AccessRights -ne "AvailabilityOnly"}| select Identity,User,AccessRights} | Export-Csv C:\CSVs\calstest.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I tested this without the `Where-Object` and it exported successfully. If you are not receiving any information you might want look more into your `Where` . Start with one condition and increase as needed.

Comment: In your case it returns this for accessrights in CSV file. "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[Microsoft.Exchange.Management.StoreTasks.MailboxFolderAccessRight]". It;s ok though, I found a way to do it by assigning foreach to a new variable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$allmailbox = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize 20
Foreach ($Mailbox in $allmailbox){Get-MailboxFolderPermission –Identity ($mailbox.alias+':\calendar') | 
Where {
    ($_.User -like "Anonymous" -and $_.AccessRights -ne "None") -or 
    ($_.User -like "Default" -and $_.AccessRights -ne "None") -or 
    ($_.User -like "Default" -and $_.AccessRights -ne "AvailabilityOnly")
    }| select Identity,User,AccessRights} | Export-CSV C:\CSVs\calstest.csv
```

If that's what you're looking for, though you'll have to add backticks I think for it to be seen as a complete query

Comment: You cannot pipe a `ForEach ($x in $y){}` loop without enclosing it in something like a scriptblock or subexpression. To make your code work modify it to `. { ForEach ($mailbox in $allmailbox){ ... }| select Identity,User,AccessRights} } | Export-Csv C:\CSVs\calstest.csv -NoTypeInfo` (added `-notypeinfo` as well to get rid of that pesky first line of junk that `Export-Csv` generates that nobody seems to want)

Comment: Yes, I did something like this {$result = ForEach ($x in $y) | $result | Export-CSV} etc and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$allmailbox = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize 500
$result = Foreach ($Mailbox in $allmailbox){Get-MailboxFolderPermission –Identity ($mailbox.alias+':\calendar') | Where {$_.User -like "Anonymous" -and $_.AccessRights -ne "None" -or $_.User -like "Default" -and $_.AccessRights -ne "None" -or $_.User -like "Default" -and $_.AccessRights -ne "AvailabilityOnly"} | select Identity,User,AccessRights}
$result | Export-CSV C:\CSVs\calstest.csv -NoType
```